# didSelectViewController not being called when switching tabs manually

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar interface with three tabs.  I would like them to animate when I switch between them.  I implemented didSelectViewController (and all the associated delegate stuff) which is called when I press the tabs but not when I switch tabs programmatically.  The docs say as much,

"In iOS v3.0 and later, the tab bar controller calls this method regardless of whether the selected view controller changed. In addition, it is called only in response to user taps in the tab bar and is not called when your code changes the tab bar contents programmatically."

Anyone know any workarounds?

Thanks!   - Jon

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are switching them programmatically why can't you create proper animation yourself? I mean you do know which tab gets selected, right?

Answer (score 0):

you can call the method when you switch them programmatically yourself. or write another method to do your animation and call IT whenever you switch tabs programatically